# How can I create editable mulitple columns in UITableview?

Tags: xcode, uitableview, multiple-columns

I have experimented and follow different tutorials to understand UItableView in xcode. I am starting to understand it, but I can't figure out how I can create 2 columns. Like this: http://blog.rockymountaintraining.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/fig2.jpg

I *also* want the cells to be editable.

Does this make sense?

Thanks.

Comment: UITableView is a single column of cells. Look at UICollectionView.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by to columns? Did you read manuals? On the youtube enough tutorials how to create tableview.

Comment: I have updated the first post. Of course I have! I have checked on YouTube, but I can't find a tutorial which does this.

Comment: If you'd like to edit cells. you should implement delegate methods of tableview. Than tell to your tableview that is editable. Search in SO before asking. Here are lot of answers to your question.